# error TS1248: A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword.[];

Tags: angular

I am working on angular 2 MEAN application development. I am facing below issue

> error TS1248: A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword.[];

I have declared below const array. I want to use this array to any function where I need.

```
const ballmasterObj: Array<any> = [];
```

I have a function which updates this array for ex. code below.

```
var obj= {};
      obj.ovrnum= "2";
      obj['balls']=[];
      var ballObj = {};
      ballObj['balllN'] = "4";
      ballObj['key'] = "3380dkasfka";
      obj['balls'].push(ballObj);

this.ballmasterObj.push(obj);
```

This individual obj is in a loop to push individual objects to master obj which is array.

I can understand from error that I cannot have a const keyword in class. I am new to typescript and angular 2 as well.

I have looked up for the issue on google search but did not come to any conclusion.

Comment: "I have declared below const array". Where?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You do not have to have const when you declare it, this should do

```
ballmasterObj: Array<any> = [];
```

however if you really want to have a const value in your class,  TypeScript 2.0 has the **`readonly`** modifier